# Why doesn't rvalue destroy right after it's used?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I wrote the following program and expected that the rvalue gotten from `std::move()` would be destroyed right after it's used in the function call:

```
struct A
{
    A(){ }
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "A&" << std::endl; }
    ~A(){ std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
    A operator=(const A&){ std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl; return A();}
};

void foo(const A&&){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }

int main(){
    const A& a = A();
    foo(std::move(a)); //after evaluation the full-expression 
                       //rvalue should have been destroyed
    std::cout << "before ending the program" << std::endl;
}
```

But it was not. The following output was produced instead:

```
foo()
before ending the program
~A()
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4d4e5f8b39f222c)

As said in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/3663882)

> rvalues denote temporary objects which are destroyed at the next
>   semicolon

What did I get wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I think this question is an opportunity to clarify the meaning of `std::move`

Comment: Point to the code that you expected to destroy the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::move` does not make `a` into a temporary value. Rather it creates an rvalue reference to `a`, which is used in function `foo`. In this case `std::move` is not doing anything for you.

The point of `std::move` is that you can indicate that a *move constructor* should be used instead of a *copy constructor*, or that a function being called is free to modify the object in a destructive way. It doesn't automatically cause your object to be destructed.

So what `std::move` does here is that *if it wanted to*, the function `foo` could modify `a` in a destructive way (since it takes an rvalue reference as its argument). But `a` is still an lvalue. Only the reference is an rvalue.

There's a great reference [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) that explains rvalue references in detail, perhaps that will clear a few things up.

Comment: But the fact that an rvalue, not an rvalue reference to lvalue is being detroyed after a full-expression it contains has finished is correct?

Comment: Yes. For example, try this: `foo(A())`. The temporary `A` object will be destroyed after the semicolon.

Comment: `std::move(a)` cannot trigger the move constructor in this specific example, because `a` is a const lvalue, hence `std::move(a)` is a const rvalue, but rvalue references do not bind to const rvalues.

Comment: rvalue references are in the language: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references/

Answer (score 2):

Remember: `std::move` doesn't move the object. `std::move` is a simple cast that takes an lvalue and makes it *look* like an rvalue

`foo`, by taking an argument by rvalue reference, says that the input object will be modified, but left in a valid state. Nothing here about destroying the object.

In the end, `a` remains an lvalue, no matter how much you try to cast it.

Answer (score 2):

`std::move(a)` does not alter `a` to become an rvalue.

Instead, it creates an rvalue reference to `a`.

---

Edit:

Note that, with your line

```
const A& a = A();
```

you rely on a the special case of local const references prolonging the lives of temporaries (see e.g. http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). This feature predates C++11. As temporaries are basically rvalues, I understand now where your confusion comes from.

Note that by prolonging the life of the temporary (by means of assigning it to the local const reference), your object referenced by **`a`** cannot be classified as "object(s) which are destroyed at the next semicolon". Rather, it lives as long as the reference.

May someone else locate http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ in the C++11 standard. Same for your sentence "rvalues denote temporary objects which are destroyed at the next semicolon".

Answer (score 1):

The rvalue you get from `std::move` is an rvalue reference, and references don't have a destructor. You can't get to that reference anymore. So why don't you think it has been destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get anything wrong; rather, it is the committee that made a mistake in giving `std::move` that name. It's just a cast, making it easier to "select" move constructors and move assignment operators that actually perform moves. In this case you have neither, so the `std::move` does literally nothing. You're seeing the original object being destroyed when it goes out of scope as usual.